# My implementation of a `Runnable` cannot resolve a method on an object of a declared interface

Tags: java, interface, compiler-errors, runnable

I have a simple `Runnable` implementation in Java 15.

```java
package work.basil.example;

public class MonsterRunnable < Monster > implements Runnable
{
    private final Monster monster;

    // Constructor
    public MonsterRunnable ( Monster monster )
    {
        this.monster = monster;
    }

    @Override
    public void run ( )
    {
        this.monster.actOut(); //  Compiler error: Cannot resolve method 'actOut' in 'Monster'
    }
}
```

The compiler in my IDE (IntelliJ 2020.3) cannot resolve the method `actOut` on the `this.monster.actOut();`  line of the `run` method.

Yet that method is clearly defined on the interface, shown next.

```java
package work.basil.example;

public sealed interface Monster
        permits Demon, Witch
{
    String name ( ); // This getter method implemented implicitly by `record` in our concrete classes `Demon` & `Witch`.

    public void actOut ( );  //  Method is declared, yet cannot be resolved in `Runnable`. 
}
```

My little demo app is using the Java 15 preview features [*JEP 360: Sealed Classes (Preview)*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/360) and [*JEP 384: Records (Second Preview)*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/384). But I do not see how that might be a source of trouble here.

---

I suppose the above should be enough code for the Question. But I can show the pair of implementations of the interface, `Demon` and `Witch`.

```java
package work.basil.example;

public record Demon(String name) implements Monster
{
    @Override
    public void actOut ( )
    {
        System.out.println( "This monster " + this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " named " + this.name + " buys a soul." );
    }
}
```

… and …

```java
package work.basil.example;

public record Witch(String name) implements Monster
{
    @Override
    public void actOut ( )
    {
        System.out.println( "This monster " + this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " named " + this.name + " casts a spell." );
    }
}
```

Finally, here is a demonstration of the `actOut` method working — if I kill the line `this.monster.actOut();` in the offending `run` method.

```java
package work.basil.example;

/**
 * Hello world!
 */
public class MonterMash
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
        MonterMash monterMash = new MonterMash();
        monterMash.demo();
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        Monster monster = new Witch( "Rowena" );
        System.out.println( "monster = " + monster );
        monster.actOut();
    }
}
```

When run:

> Hello World!
>
> monster = Witch[name=Rowena]
>
> This monster Witch named Rowena casts a spell.

Comment: The problem is that you are using Monster as your generic type. Try making it not generic: `public class MonsterRunnable {` or if it needs to be generic use T

Comment: @sprinter Yes! Deleting the generics works. Changing `public class MonsterRunnable < Monster > implements Runnable` to `public class MonsterRunnable implements Runnable` makes the compiler happy. But why? The actually goal of this entire experiment was to get a generics type declared for a `Runnable` implementation.  And please post an Answer for me to accept.

Comment: Because `Monster` use just a generic type without bounds, so it can be anything. Just like `List<E>` where `E` can be anything as well (here your `Monster` is exactly the same as `E`). That's why you should very rarely use actual words for generic types, those can be confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature `public class MonsterRunnable < Monster > implements Runnable` introduces a generic parameter `Monster` for `MonsterRunnable`. A generic parameter makes a class .. generic. That means you can use the class with whatever type.

E.g. when you use a `List<String>`, `<String>` is the argument, the type of the elements. `List` itself is declared as `public interface List<E> extends Collection<E>`. Notice that `E` is the generic parameter; a variable of type `List<String>` uses that parameter to reference a list of `String`s. You can also reference a list of `Integer`s: `List<Integer>`. You can use `List` with whatever element type as it is generic by having the generic parameter `E`. `E` is for "element" and is Java convention: see [**Type Parameter Naming Conventions**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html). `E` is used within `List` to express methods and so on.

So here in your example, the generic parameter `Monster` "hides" the type `Monster`, which is *your* class. The introduced generic type `Monster` doesn't have the method `actOut`, which is what the compiler tells you.

What you want is that `monster` is of a type that extends `Monster`, simple inheritance. Therefore, just drop the generic parameter and you'll have what you want:

```java
public class MonsterRunnable implements Runnable
```

---

Your note in the comment section:

> The actually goal of this entire experiment was to get a generics type declared for a Runnable implementation.

You need to express that the generic in `MonsterRunnable` is an implementation of `Monster`:

```java
package work.basil.example;

public class MonsterRunnable < T extends Monster > implements Runnable
{
    private final T monster;

    // Constructor
    public MonsterRunnable ( T monster )
    {
        this.monster = monster;
    }

    @Override
    public void run ( )
    {
        this.monster.actOut();
    }
}
```

Now `MonsterRunnable` is generic by using `T`, which is restricted to extend (implement) `Monster`.